# Images to video in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, video, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have some images and want to make a video with them. I found lots of ways for this purpose, like [AForge.NET](http://www.aforgenet.com/) or [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) but non of them are supported in windows phone.

My purpose is simple, just to combine images and make a video, but it is surprising that there is no way in `.NET` for a simple job like this.

Please help me, I paid some reputations if I had but I can't sorrily.

Comment: you can make a gif image instead!

Comment: Hi @Anirudh thanks. No I want to make a video.

Answer (score 0):

Please Use this,

```
int current = 0;
List myFiles = new List()
                {
                 // Put your multiple images here..
                “Monkey_Images/img_tablet1.png”,
                “Monkey_Images/img_tablet2.png”,
                “Monkey_Images/img_tablet3.png”,
                “Monkey_Images/img_tablet4.png”,
                “Monkey_Images/img_tablet5.png”,
                “Monkey_Images/img_tablet6.png”,
                “Monkey_Images/img_tablet7.png”
                };

DispatcherTimer dtimer = new DispatcherTimer();

List bmps = new List() { };

public void MonkeyMovement()
{
      foreach (string ff in myFiles)
      {
        BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri(ff, UriKind.Relative));
        bmps.Add(bmp);   // Temporary assign images into bitmapimage list.
      }
      dtimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(20);
      dtimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dtimer_Tick);
      dtimer.Start();
}

void dtimer_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     imgLoading.Source = bmps[current];
        current++;
        if (current >= 6)
        {
            current = 0;
        }
}
```

It seems like video is playing but actually its a multiple images.
I hope you get the solution.
For more information please refer my blog [**DotNetterNikhil**](http://dotnetternikhil.blogspot.in)

Comment: Thanks @Nikhil, sorry but I need a real video which I can play and share it with others.

Answer (score 0):

How about [motion jpeg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG)

> Motion JPEG (M-JPEG or MJPEG) is a video format in which each video
>   frame or interlaced field of a digital video sequence is compressed
>   separately as a JPEG image.

Also [MJPEG Decoder](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/MJPEG-Decoder) can be helpful for you.

Comment: thanks @Andrei . I looked at its codes, but my purpose seems in reverse. I don't know if there is a way to make that stream of images.

Comment: I have asked a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584753/how-to-make-a-mjpeg-video-of-some-images

Comment: Well you have a decoder fully written (http://mjpeg.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#MJPEG/MjpegProcessor/MjpegDecoder.cs) in C#. There is nothing difficult to write an encoder.

Comment: Thanks Andrei. I think for adding audio layer, I need to combine audio and video in an `AVI` file, which I return to the first step since I couldn't find an `AVI` encoder in past days.